# Problem with multi-threaded construction of Nef Polyhedrons from a same Polyhedron

Tags: c++, cgal

I have a multi-thread program in which a set of 3D Nef Polyhedrons might be constructed from a same polyhedron, the simplified code can be demonstrated as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <future>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Nef_polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/boost/graph/convert_nef_polyhedron_to_polygon_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/measure.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/triangulate_faces.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Exact_kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Exact_kernel> Polyhedron;
typedef CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_3<Exact_kernel> Nef_polyhedron;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("mesh_a.off");
    Polyhedron poly;
    CGAL::read_off(ifs, poly);
    CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::triangulate_faces(poly);

    std::vector<std::future<void>> futureVec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        auto fun = [&poly]() {
            Nef_polyhedron N1(poly);
            std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
        };
        futureVec.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, fun));
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < futureVec.size(); i++)
        futureVec[i].get();

    return 0;
}
```

The content of mesh_a.off file is:

```
OFF
16 6 0
0.63 0 0
1.26 0 0
0.965876 0.294124 0
0.909198 0.245717 0
0.845645 0.206772 0
0.776783 0.178248 0
0.704306 0.160848 0
0.63 0.155 0
0.63 0 0.5
1.26 0 0.5
0.965876 0.294124 0.5
0.909198 0.245717 0.5
0.845645 0.206772 0.5
0.776783 0.178248 0.5
0.704306 0.160848 0.5
0.63 0.155 0.5
8  7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
8  8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
4  0 1 9 8
4  1 2 10 9
12  2 3 4 5 6 7 15 14 13 12 11 10
4  7 0 8 15
```

If the code above works normally, the word "test" should be printed **10 times**. However, the number of print times differs at each execution and at most time it **doesn't print anything**. It seems something wrong with construction of Nef Polyhedron causing an unexpected thread quit, although no exception throw. The print behavior performs normally if I move the line of print code to the upper line of Nef Polyhedron construction.

I run the program on Windows and the IDE is Visual Studio 2019.

So what's wrong with this code? How can I construct Nef polyhedrons from a same polyhedron using multi-thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux, your program aborts with

> free(): corrupted unsorted chunks

`CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel` is not thread-safe currently, reading the same number in 2 threads can lead to corruption. There is a PR to make it thread-safe: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/5402 but it hasn't been merged yet.

Without this branch, one workaround could be to use `Simple_cartesian<mpq_class>` or a similar kernel, but that's going to be slower than doing your construction sequentially with Epeck.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I tried to replace the kernel with `Simple_cartesian` or `Cartesian`, while an assertion violation occurred with some of my off files, see [Assertion violation with 'ss_circle.has_on' when constructing Nef_polyhedron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68116602/assertion-violation-with-ss-circle-has-on-when-constructing-nef-polyhedron). Do you have any idea of this issue?

Comment: Do not use `Cartesian`, it has the same thread-unsafe issue. It has to be `Simple_cartesian`. And the number type has to be mpq_class or boost's mpq_rational (or possibly LEDA, but not Gmpq for instance). You can put it inside Filtered_kernel though if that helps performance a bit.