# Assertion violation with 'ss_circle.has_on' when constructing Nef_polyhedron

Tags: c++, cgal

I want to construct an object of `Nef_polyhedron_3` using `Polyhedron_3`, while an assertion violation occurred with error description as:

```
CGAL error: assertion violation!
Expression : ss_circle.has_on(sp)
File       : ***\CGAL\Nef_3\polygon_mesh_to_nef_3.h
Line       : 255
Explanation:
Refer to the bug-reporting instructions at https://www.cgal.org/bug_report.html
```

Here is the simplified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <future>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Nef_polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/triangulate_faces.h>

typedef CGAL::Cartesian<double> Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Polyhedron;
typedef CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_3<Kernel> Nef_polyhedron;

void fill_cube(Polyhedron& poly)
{
    std::string input = R"(
OFF
5 5 0
1.10339 0.590945    0.0384615
1.10338 0.590775    0
1.105   0.63    0
1.105   0.63    0.0384615
1.1361  0.609828    0
4   3   2   1   0
3   2   4   1
3   2   3   4
3   3   0   4
3   0   1   4
)";
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << input;
    ss >> poly;
}

int main()
{
    Polyhedron cube;
    fill_cube(cube);
    CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::triangulate_faces(cube);
    Nef_polyhedron N(cube);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code could work if `Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel` is used instead, but a thread safety problem arose, see my another question [Problem with multi-threaded construction of Nef Polyhedrons from a same Polyhedron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68086180/problem-with-multi-threaded-construction-of-nef-polyhedrons-from-a-same-polyhedr).

The program runs on *Windows* with *VS2019*.

So how can I resolve this issue?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are using `double` and are thus at the mercy of all rouding issues. You need to use an exact number type instead. Although the simplest would be to stick to Epeck and not use parallelism...

Answer (score 0):

Replace `CGAL::Cartesian<double>` by a kernel with exact constructions like `CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel`.

More details [here](https://www.cgal.org/FAQ.html#inexact_NT)